# Static typing of the Axios request methods

Tags: typescript, axios

In my utility method I make use of the Axios request methods as follows:

```
const response = await axios[method](url, body);
```

where the arguments conform with an interface

```
import { Method } from 'axios';

interface UseRequestProps {
  url: string;
  method: Lowercase<Method>;
  body: any;
}
```

Though the `method` argument gets narrowed down to

```
UseRequestProps.method: "get" | "delete" | "head" | "options" | "post" | "put" | "patch" | "purge" | "link" | "unlink"
```

I'm still getting an error of

```
TS7052: Element implicitly has an any type because type AxiosStatic has no index signature. Did you mean to call axios.get
```

that doesn't happen when I define the `method` argument as a union type with fewer request types:

```
interface UseRequestProps {
  url: string;
  method: "get" | "delete" | "head" | "options" | "post" | "put" | "patch";
  body: any;
}
```

What's the difference between the two variations? How do I get the first version to work?

Answer (score 0):

The methods `"purge" | "link" | "unlink"` weren't on the Axios request types.
The solution was to intersect the `Method` and the Axios request types with

```
interface UseRequestProps {
  ...
  method: Lowercase<Method> & keyof typeof axios;
  ...
}
```